# Definition of ordered ring flawed?

Tags: ring-theory

Wikipedia says an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) has these two properties:

$a \leq b \rightarrow a+c \leq b+c$

$0 \leq a \land 0 \leq b \rightarrow 0 \leq ab$

Later the article says:

$a \leq b \land 0 \leq c \rightarrow ac \leq bc$ "This property is sometimes used to define ordered rings instead of the second property in the definition above."

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Assume we have a finite ring, $Z/3Z$, and a [total cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) defined by $B(0,1,2)$ which means $1$ comes between $0$ and $2$.

$(x \leq y) =: (x=y \lor x=0 \lor B(0,x,y))$

This definition seems to satisfy $0 \leq a \land 0 \leq b \rightarrow 0 \leq ab$ but not $a \leq b \land 0 \leq c \rightarrow ac \leq bc$. Every number is positive with this definition so $0 \leq ab$ is always true. But, let a=1, b=2 and c=2 and then (1*2 > 2*2) mod 3.

Comment: But it doesn't satisfy the first property: $1 \le 2$ but $1+1 > 2+1$.

Comment: Perhaps a slightly better title is in order. Perhaps something which doesn't come off as "mathematics is wrong and I'm right" and more along the lines of "I probably missed something, but I'm not sure what".

Comment: Note that despite the phrase you use (which I don't think is standard), a total cyclic order is not a *total order*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property "$a\le b\implies a+c\le b+c$" does not hold in the structure you describe, however. The third property listed is a consequence of the *two* properties in the definition, together - the equivalence mentioned is relative to the first property, as well as the axioms of total order (which a cyclic order does not satisfy of course).

Comment: My mistake. For some reason I thought $B(a,b,c) \rightarrow B(a+x,b+x,c+x)$ meant $a+x < b+x$. Of course, this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic orders are not partial orders (so in particular not total orders) because they are not antisymmetric. Which is part of the requirements of $\leq$ in an ordered ring.